# Python 3 floating point operations with loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand why the sequence of operations forward and backward produces different final results (293.02992793 vs 293.02992793000004)? Could you please help with the explanation?

```
cf = [100, 50, 40, 20, 30, 25]
rate  = 1.03
FV = 0
for i in range(len(cf)): 
    print(i,' ',FV)
    FV += cf[i] * rate**(len(cf)-i-1)       
print(FV)

FV = 0
i = len(cf) - 1
while i>=0:
    print(i,' ',FV)
    FV += cf[i] * rate**(len(cf)-i-1) 
    i = i-1
print(FV)

cf = cf[::-1]
FV = 0
for i in range(len(cf)): 
    print(i,' ',FV)
    FV += cf[i] * rate**(i)       
print(FV)
```

0     0

1     115.92740743

2    172.20284793000002

3    215.91192793000002

4   237.12992793

5   268.02992793

293.02992793

5   0

4   25.0

3   55.900000000000006

2   77.11800000000001

1   120.82708000000001

0   177.10252050000003

293.02992793000004

0   0

1   25.0

2   55.900000000000006

3   77.11800000000001

4   120.82708000000001

5   177.10252050000003

293.02992793000004

Comment: I think an error of about 0.0000000000001% is probably not too shabby for floating point :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I do accept but for very end-users, they may not, and at least, I will be expected to explain them.